# Grails - Two properties of same type and one does not persist to the database, no errors

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Grails 2.0.1

Here are stripped down simplified versions of the Domains:

```
class Attribute {
   String name

   static hasMany = [attributeParameters: AttributeParameter]
}

class AttributeParameter {
   String name

   Attribute attributeReference

   static belongsTo = [attribute:Attribute]
}
```

When I look at the schema in the database, there are 2 separate FKs in AttributeParameter; 1 for the attribute_reference_id, and one for attribute_id. When I save the domains populated with all their data I am getting 0 errors on both Attribute and AttributeParameter, however, the attribute_reference_id column never gets populated.  Debugging, I can see the attributeReference object and it has an ID, even after the save call(s).  Grails is not throwing any exceptions (at least none that are being displayed on the console).

Stranger still is that if I go to the database and add the ID of an attribute into the attribute_reference_id column, GORM loads it perfectly. Hitting save again, it goes back to null even though debugging shows the object present.

Really at a loss as to why the data isn't persisting.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the following to Attribute:

```
static mappedBy = [attributeParameters: 'attribute']
```

Comment: This domain modeling makes no sense. Are you trying to accomplish a 1:M between Attribute and AttributeParameter? If so, remove the attributeReference field, as the belongsTo block automatically attaches the defined field (in this case attribute) to your domain class.

Comment: They are 2 separate properties, as I stated in my question.  One defines the belongsTo / hasMany relationship, the attributeReference is another property we need to track.